# How to pass parameter to Bitbucket pipeline pipe included in a step definition?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following Bitbucket pipeline

```
# This image is used in both "Zip and Upload to S3 steps"
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          # Include this step so that we can get a successful build when any
          # commit is made to a branch. This will allow us to merge to the
          # staging branch which requires a successful commit previously
          - echo "The current branch is $BITBUCKET_BRANCH"

  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          # We have decided to include the Zip and upload to S3 sections of the
          # pipeline in the same step because of a bug in the pipeline within
          # artifacts. See https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-21666 for
          # details.
          name: Zip & Upload to S3
          services:
            - docker
          oidc: true
          script:
            # Build the zip file containing the contents of the applications
            # folder
            - zip -r $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.zip "applications"
            # Upload the zip file to S3
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:1.1.1
              variables:
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
                AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN: $AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN
                COMMAND: "upload"
                APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.zip
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET_STAGING
                VERSION_LABEL: $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG

      - step:
          name: Deploy code
          deployment: staging
          oidc: true
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:1.1.1
              variables:
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
                AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN: $AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN
                APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
                COMMAND: "deploy"
                DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: $DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_STAGING
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET_STAGING
                WAIT: "true"
                FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: OVERWRITE
                VERSION_LABEL: $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG

    production:
      - step:
          # We have decided to include the Zip and upload to S3 sections of the
          # pipeline in the same step because of a bug in the pipeline within
          # artifacts. See https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-21666 for
          # details.
          name: Zip & Upload to S3
          services:
            - docker
          oidc: true
          script:
            # Build the zip file
            - zip -r $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.zip "applications"
            # Upload the zip file to S3
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:1.1.1
              variables:
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
                AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN: $AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN
                COMMAND: "upload"
                APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.zip
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET_PROD
                VERSION_LABEL: $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG

      - step:
          name: Deploy code
          deployment: production
          oidc: true
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:1.1.1
              variables:
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
                AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN: $AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN
                APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
                COMMAND: "deploy"
                DEPLOYMENT_GROUP: $DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_PROD
                S3_BUCKET: $S3_BUCKET_PROD
                WAIT: "true"
                FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR: OVERWRITE
                VERSION_LABEL: $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
```

As you can see, the staging and production branches are almost identical. The only differences are:

1. The use of "staging" or "production" in the "deployment" variable
2. The S3_BUCKET variable that is different depending on whether we are deploying to staging or production.

To avoid duplicate code, I want to create a step definition that I can reuse. So for example, the definition for the "Zip and Upload to S3" step would look something like below

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &EchoCurrentBranch
        name: Echo current branch
        script:
          - echo "The current branch is $BITBUCKET_BRANCH"

    - step: &ZipAndUploadToS3
        name: ⬆️ Zip & Upload to S3
        services:
          - docker
        oidc: true
        script:
          # Build the zip file containing the contents of the applications
          # folder
          - zip -r $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.zip "applications"
          # Upload the zip file to S3
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:1.1.1
            variables:
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_REGION
              AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN: $AWS_OIDC_ROLE_ARN
              COMMAND: "upload"
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG.zip
              S3_BUCKET: <I want this variable to be changeable>
              VERSION_LABEL: $BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
```

But the problem is that I can't find a way to pass a different value for the S3 bucket into the pipeline for different calls to the defined step. How do I pass in a different value for the S3 bucket into the pipe depending on the branch that I am deploying to?

I know that it is possible to pass different values into step definitions (as shown in [Reusable Bitbucket pipelines configuration with YAML anchors](https://gist.github.com/prabhu/06245e0f5ce949aa8a93e448fbd6516c) for example) but I can't find anywhere that shows how to pass a pipe variable into a defined step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your definition mentions [Deployments](https://bitbucket.org/blog/introducing-bitbucket-deployments), but did you try to actually use it?

It's a feature that allows you to define different values for the same variable depending on the environment.

Populate your deployments with variables and adjust your pipeline definition. The result should look similar to

```yaml
pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          <<: *&ZipAndUploadToS3
          deployment: upload-staging
      - step:
          <<: *&Deploy
          deployment: deploy-staging

    production:
      - step: 
          <<: *&ZipAndUploadToS3
          deployment: upload-production
      - step:
          <<: *&Deploy
          deployment: deploy-production
```

More on Deployments: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/#Deployment-variables

Comment: Hi @esimonov. I did try to pass the deployment separately to each but the problem is that the deployment variable is already being used in the `Deploy code` step. And it is not possible to use the deployment variable more than once in the pipeline. That means when I have `deployment: staging` in the `Deploy code` step I can't also include it in the `Zip & Upload to S3` step unfortunately. I could combine the steps and then rely on `deployment` but I don't think the steps should be combined.

Comment: In my workplace, we use different deployments for build and deploy stages. Deployment does not necessarily need to directly translate to an environment: having 4 separate deployments, e.g `upload-staging`, `deploy-staging`, `upload-production`, and `deploy-production` is completely fine.

Comment: Do you mean I can set the `deployment` variable to any of `upload-staging`, `deploy-stating`, etc? And then create those different environments with variables under `https://bitbucket.org/<repo_name>/admin/addon/admin/pipelines/deployment-settings`

Comment: Absolutely. This way, you'll avoid using the same deployment twice (which is, as you mentioned, not allowed). Create the S3_BUCKET variable with the same value in both `upload-` and `deploy-` deployments, but different across environments, as required in your use case.

Comment: I updated the example in my answer for your convenience.

Comment: I'll absolutely give this a go and come back to you

Comment: This sucks, because Deployments maps directly to your tickets. So, a ticket would be "deployed" to upload-staging and also deploy-staging, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

**Use of Deployments just to pass environment specific arguments is a hack**

If you have a unique build deployment then your app will count as a "deployment". If you use Jira, your branch that has only built, will show up in Jira as being deployed. This will also affect stats on lead time from first commit to being released. Also, what about the variable that are the same in both your build deployment and release deployment - you'll have to duplicate them!

**Here's another hack (because bitbucket forces us to!)**

Define any arguments to be passed to other steps by echoing export statements to a script file like this:

```
  - step:
      artifacts:
        - set_env.sh
      script:
        - echo "export APP_ID=devtest/broker-insights-frontend/app" >> set_env.sh
```

Then, any step wanting to use them would execute that file using `source`, thus create environment variables.

```
    - step: &load-vars
        name: 'Load vars'
        script:
          - source set_env.sh
          - printenv APP_ID
```

**BE AWARE** of any sensitive ENV variables present while capturing them into an artifact, these will be saved in plain text to anyone with access to download artifacts from the pipeline.